# Extract topology into a TIFF file

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, mapzen

I want to extract the topology of the island is Hawai'i but when I try to do it, I get simply and empty rectangle:

[image]

I opened OSM in XYZ tiles and press the right mouse button on the layer of OSM `export -> save as`  I clicked `map canvas extend` and checked off `Create VRT` (if I leave `create VRT` check then I get `Cannot write raster. Error code: destination provider`).

I did the same with Mapzen global terrain and got (with `Create VRT` check or not checked, doesn't matter):

[image]

How do I export the topology of Hawaii with the contour lines and so on from OSM (or some other map provider)?

Comment: Do you want a picture of the topology (with contours and coastline etc) or the actual data as raw height values?

Comment: @IanTurton a tiff file that has both I guess. An image that has this information embedded in it I'd say.

Comment: I think you mean *topography*, not topology